# ConcurrentHashMap read while resizing

Tags: concurrenthashmap

I would like to know the possible scenarios that can occur when we are trying to read a ConcurrentHashMap while it is resizing.

I know that during read, first attempt is always unsynchronized. In second attempt it will try to acquire lock and retry.

But if it happens during resizing how would it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

By looking at the source:

A ConcurrentHashMap contains one or more segments, depending on the concurrency level.

During a rehash, a segment is locked and the new table is built next to the old table then replaces it at the end.

If you call `get()` during the rehash of a segment and your key is stored in that segment, you will access the old table of the segment without lock and if found and the value is not null, it will be returned. If the value is null, the call will block until the rehash is done and the value will be read again under lock.

Answer (score 2):

**For Java 8/11,**

Let's see `get()` method first,

```java
   /**
     * Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped,
     * or {@code null} if this map contains no mapping for the key.
     *
     * <p>More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key
     * {@code k} to a value {@code v} such that {@code key.equals(k)},
     * then this method returns {@code v}; otherwise it returns
     * {@code null}.  (There can be at most one such mapping.)
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified key is null
     */
    public V get(Object key) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;
        int h = spread(key.hashCode());
        if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
            (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) {
            if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {
                if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))  // found and just return
                    return e.val;
            }
            else if (eh < 0)   // -1 for forwarding node or red tree
                return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;
            while ((e = e.next) != null) { // iterate linked list
                if (e.hash == h &&
                    ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))))
                    return e.val;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Java 8 replace segment lock with spin lock(CAS and loop) and synchronized on first node of collision bucket to obtain better concurrent performance.

There are two table used for resizing, and force it visible by `volatile` declaration.

```java
    /**
     * The array of bins. Lazily initialized upon first insertion.
     * Size is always a power of two. Accessed directly by iterators.
     */
    transient volatile Node<K,V>[] table;

    /**
     * The next table to use; non-null only while resizing.
     */
    private transient volatile Node<K,V>[] nextTable;
```

Resizing is basically copies data from `table` to `nextTable`. After it completes, nextTable will set to `table`, and old `table` will be free as garbage.

Now when find target bucket by `get` method, if it hasn't been processed yet, we just find value by comparing key. If it has been moved into new table, a forwarding node will be set in this bucket, pointing to the new table, so `e.find(h, key)` will search bucket in `nextTable` by key.