# How reading will happen when resizing is going in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, concurrenthashmap

Assume there are 2 threads. Both the threads are working on same Hashtable of Concurrent HashMap.

Thread T1 is reading by calling map.get() not iterating and thread T2 is putting objects in same HashTable of ConcurrentHashMap.

Now if threshold level is reached, hence T2 will try to resize the Hashtable in Concurrent HashMap.
So, whether T1 will be blocked for reading or it will read from old cached structure?

Answer:
I assume as value and Entry<K,V> of  Entry Class are **volatile** it will give us last updated value from main memory directly.
No dirty read or cached reading.

I have read many blogs and even javadoc, none of them provide clear answer for this scenario. Let me know your inputs.

Comment: Option 2 is the opposite of thread safe.

Comment: When you say reading, do you mean iterating? Because otherwise the question is somewhat pointless.

Comment: Not sure if duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010519/2550406

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConcurrentHashMap read while resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009989/concurrenthashmap-read-while-resizing)

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). **Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset**. (More formally, an update operation for a
>   given key bears ahappens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval
>   for that key reporting the updated value.) For aggregate operations
>   such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion
>   or removal of only some entries. **Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators
>   and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash
>   table at some point at or since the creation of the
>   iterator/enumeration**. They do not
>   throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed
>   to be used by only one thread at a time.

Therefore, if you are iterating over `ConcurrentHashMap` instance while another thread modifies it, nothing bad will happen nor your thread will be blocked, you will just see some older snapshot.

See also:

- [How ConcurrentHashMap Internally Works In Java With Example](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-concurrenthashmap-works-in-java-internal-implementation.html?m=1)
- [How ConcurrentHashMap Works Internally in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/how-concurrenthashmap-works-internally-in-java)

Comment: To me, the question sounds more like a "How does it work internally?" than a "Will something bad happen?". The links don't seem to cover resizing

Comment: @lucidbrot Question basically boils to „So, whether T1 will be blocked for reading or it will read from old cached Structure?“ and the answer is provided in the documentation excerpt (resizing is just a special case of modification). The links at the end are not directly related to resizing, but provide further reading for better understanding of ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood:

During a rehash, a segment is locked and the new table is built next to the old table, then this old table is removed and hashcode generator is updated to provide latest hashcode which will point to the newly created segment.

So the hascode generator can give the reader thread the id of either the old segment or the new segment. 
If the reader thread got id of **new segment**, it means that already resizing is done. So no issue here. 
If reader thread got id of **old segment**, then we have two possibilities:
1. The reader thread finds the value in the segment, It means that the resizer thread possibly is still constructing the new segments.
2. Before the segment is checked by the reader thread, the resizer thread started creating new table and the hashcode generator is updated so that the next read operatios will get hashcode from this new location. And the resizing operation is now started deleting the old segment records.
Now the reader thread still have old segment address and that is now scheduled to run, so it will get null value, so in this case, the call will get blocked, and the value will be re-read. **We can assume** that the reader thread just contacted the hashcode generator and found that the resizing is done so the reader thread will have to get the new hashcode.